# Docker, AlpineLinux and Ubuntu - why does `node_modules` different

Tags: node.js, docker, gitlab, node-modules, pm2

## Environment

I do use CI/CD of gitlab to bundle my application.
I do use `node:14-alpine` as image and do run yarn to build my app.

After build is finished, I do deploy my app via rsync to the target-server, which run's `ubuntu 20.04`.

On this server, I do use pm2 to start the app and keep it running.

## Issue

If I look into the logs, I do see an error like this:
[image]

I've searched a bit, and found that the issue might be caused of `musl-dev` is missing.
I've installed it at my `server`, and into the `docker`-container, but with same result.

BUT, if I do delete the `node_modules` directory from server, and run `yarn install` right at the Server, the app run like expected

## Question

So why does this issue happens here? Must I have the same distribution & version of linux in my docker-container to fit all dependencies?

Comment: Could you share your Dockerfile?

Comment: `npm install` potentially builds platform-specific code as part of installing modules -- you should use the same operating system for building `node_modules` as you deploy on.

Comment: are you running the final image from the CICD pipeline on the ubuntu server or just the binaries?

Comment: You tagged this as a Docker issue; a Docker image should usually be self-contained, and it shouldn't matter what's installed on the host.  Do you have a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem?  Can you reconfigure your CI system to produce error messages as text and not images, and include the text-format error in the question?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use an Alpine image if you're deploying on Ubuntu.

> So why does this issue happens here?

The fundamental [C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) implementation is different on the two (Alpine uses [musl libc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musl); Ubuntu and more or less all other distros use [GNU C Library (glibc)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_C_Library)).

Trying to move binaries (such as those that might appear in `node_modules` for native modules) built against one libc implementation to a system using the other will likely be painful or not work at all (as you noticed).

> Must I have the same distribution & version of linux in my docker-container to fit all dependencies?

If none of the dependencies use native code, then you should be able to just move things over without issues, but otherwise it'll be easiest (e.g. considering the versions of other libraries your dependencies may link against) to just use the same version as your target OS – or, if you don't want to think about that, just deploy your application as a Docker container.

Answer (score 0):

Even if the suggestion from @AKX is a good answer, I've played a bit around to figure out how to solve this special case.

Here is my solution:

1. install `musl-dev` at the server
2. link it to /lib

```sh
apt-get install musl-dev
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-musl/libc.so /lib/libc.musl-x86_64.so.1
```

In my case it's only this single dependency which cause the trouble. If I got more of this, I will follow AKX's suggestion and choose a `debian/ubuntu-like` distribution to bundle it.

Comment: Just curious: Do you have a specific reason to run Alpine in CI?

Comment: minimizing the needed CI/CD build-time on gitlab project to use the free tier as good as possible for this project.

Comment: Have you measured that using a regular `node:14` image is that much slower? What's the slow part?